# jQuery animation for expanding details issues

Tags: jquery, animation

Ok, so I'm still trying to get the hang of jQuery.

I've almost got it! I need the close button start to close but because its in the same container it starts the other animation also. Any suggestions?

Here is a jsfiddle link of my code so far http://jsfiddle.net/w39Bb/5/

```
$('.outer-shell').click( function () {
    $(this).animate({
        height: '580px'
    }, 750).addClass('selected');
    $(this).find('.inner-shell').animate({
        height: '550px'
    }, 750);
    $(this).find('.details-click').animate({
        width: "0"
    }, 400).hide(100);
    $(this).find('.image-left-small , .image-right-small').animate({
        opacity: 0
    }).hide(400);
    $(this).find('.image-left-large, .image-right-large').animate({
        opacity: 1
    }).show(0);
    $(this).find('.close').animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 1000).show();
});

$('h1.close').click(function () {
    $('.outer-shell').animate({
        height: '235px'
    }, 200).removeClass('selected');
    $('.inner-shell').animate({
        height: '229px'
    }, 200);
    $('.details-click').animate({
        width: '299px'
    }, 100).show();
    $('.image-left-small , .image-right-small').animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 100).show();
    $('.image-left-large, .image-right-large').animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 400).hide();
});

$('.outer-shell').hover( function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
```

Comment: You need to work out your script using a "id" on your outer shell and then target the shell you are referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that's what you're trying to achieve but .. add stopPropagation ?

```
$('h1.close').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // The rest is the same :)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w39Bb/6/

Comment: That works but I need the close text to disappear. after you click close.

Answer (score 0):

Will it work for you if you hide the other div which you don't want using `$('#div-to-hide').hide()`

Comment: Not sure if that'll work because I will be adding more detail div down the road.